# Rails: Stripe Button not working on first attempt (until page is reloaded)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have a rails app with a custom checkout where user clicks a button to launch Stripe modal.

Problem is that when I first visit the page and click the button, I get this error:

"Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string"

The error is coming from my controller create action:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
          email: params[:stripeEmail],
          card: params[:stripeToken]
        )
```

But then if I refresh the page instead, I can launch the modal with no issue. I thought it might be a turbolinks issue, so I added my script in a ready var:

```
<script>

       var ready;
      ready = function() {

       $('#stripe-button').on('click', function (e) {
       // Open Checkout with further options
       $name = $('input[name=f_name]').val() + " " + $('input[name=l_name]').val();
       handler.open({
         name: $name,
         description: "<%= @workshop.name %>" + " workshop",
         amount: <%= @workshop.price * 100 %>
       });
     e.preventDefault();
     });

     $(window).on('popstate', function() {
       handler.close();
     });


      var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
       key: "<%= ENV['stripe_publishable_key'] %>",
       token: function (token, args) {
         $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
         $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
         $("#stripeAmount").val('<%= j (@workshop.price * 100).to_s %>');
         $("#stripeForm").submit();
       }
     });

    };

    $(document).ready(ready);
    $(document).on('page:load', ready);


   </script>
```

But not fixed. It seems like the e.preventDefault() isn't working when the page is first loaded... But I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with implementing a custom form with Stripe.  What worked for me was to move from the application layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %>
<%= javascript_tag "Stripe.publishableKey = '#{STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}';" %>
```

to the actual view file (ex. new.html.erb) at the bottom of the page so it would be just above the ending `</body>`tag.  This means I will have to include application.js on every view not via application layout so I will probably add it to the footer.  Not sure if this is the best way, but it worked for me.

Comment: We've done the same, we have moved the JS to be inside the HTML file that renders the form, but sometimes it needs to be refreshed, any other ideas?